# window.scrollTo not working when used in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a *continue* button on my page where when a user clicks I call a validate function and if there are any errors on the page I show them on top and scroll to them with `window.scrollTo(0,0);`

Now, this page is loaded in an `iframe` and the `window.scrollTo(0,0);` doesn't work. I tried all possible ways like `window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);` or `$('#error_msg_smry').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);`, but nothing works.

Below is my code (error message div below):

```
<div id="error_msg_smry" class="error_msg_summary" style="display:none;" >
    <br/>
    <div class="error_msg_heading">Sorry, but we cannot process your donation until the following errors have been fixed:</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="error_messages">
        <div id="selDonationErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div> 
        <div id="otherAmtErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="lessDonationErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="recipientErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="firstNameErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="lastNameErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="emailErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="creditCardNameErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="creditCardNumberErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="creditCardExpiryMonthErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="creditCardExpiryYearErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
        <div id="creditCardCCVErr" class="textClass" style="color:#b94a48; font-weight:400;"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

The button below:

```
<apex:commandButton styleclass="btn" action="{!makeDonation}" onClick="return validate();" value="Continue"/>
```

And in my validate function I do the following:

```
if(isPass == false){
    document.getElementById("error_msg_smry").style.display = 'block';
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

I don't have access on the parent page (outside of my iframe).
Can anyone please help me

Comment: any updates on this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my answer if anyone facing the same issue and looking for a solution:

I resolved it writing below code:

```
  if(isPass == false){
                    document.getElementById("error_msg_smry").style.display = 'block';
                    // window.scrollTo(0,0);

                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                      div.innerHTML = "<a style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0px' href='#'></a>";
                      div = div.firstChild;
                      document.body.appendChild(div);
                      div.focus();
                      div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                 }
                else{
                   document.getElementById("error_msg_smry").style.display = 'none';
                }

                return isPass;
            }
```